# Orchard - removing administrative items from main menu

Tags: orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to work my way around orchard. I am writinga theme but I need to remove the administative items (sign in, current user) from the main menu.

I already implement a navigation provider, but I now realize that the logged in user is part of the menu. Any easy way to remove it? I find it astonishing that items jsut get added to the menu without any way to turn that off.

What I want is a main menu ONLY with the items defined in the menu (which are blog, some content) and no username etc.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Usually, you can just create a new menu in the Navigation of the dashboard, then add a menu widget where you want.

Comment: Mx own. And that is what I did not - if you put it as answer I will accept it. Still no idea where the items come from, but I now just make my own menu and do not render the "Main Menu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you can just create a new menu in the Navigation section of the Admin dashboard. After creating the menu you can go to Widgets -> add a Menu Widget, select your newly made menu and add it to a Zone.

Some themes already take the User actions out of the main menu, you could check out the corresponding template views which are used.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Layout file for the theme you are using.
C:\inetpub\MyWebsite\Themes\MyTheme\Views\Layout.cshtml

Look for the following line, and disable/delete it:

```
//WorkContext.Layout.Header.Add(New.User(), "10"); // Login and dashboard links
```

Orchard v.1.9.1.0